# Pop Up in jetpack compose is not reacting to state change properly

Tags: android, popup, android-jetpack-compose, state

The popup in jetpack compose is not reacting to state change properly.. I have the following code.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Temp() {
    val a by remember {
        mutableStateOf((1..10).map { it.toString() })
    }

    var textValue by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    val list by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            a.filter { it.contains(textValue) }
        }
    }
    Column {
        TextField(
            value = textValue,
            onValueChange = { value ->
                textValue = value
            }
        )
        Box {
            Popup {
                Column {
                    list.forEach {
                        Text(text = it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, if the list is filtered to be empty, the change is not reflected inside the popup. The UI stays as it was before the empty list. However if I remove popup, it works as expected.

Also, if I print the number of items in the list, the number of items is also 0. However items are not removed from the UI.

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report to google.

Comment: I have filed an issue in the following link.. Please feel free to check if any updates with the issue. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283876883